# wxPython (Python3) ListCtrl header with bold text/horizontal rules

Tags: python-3.x, wxwidgets, listctrl, wxpython

I'm a newbie and making a simple ListCtrl. My first impression was that it looks good on GTK but not so good on windows. The headers didn't look outstanding from the list items, so I'm trying to make it look better. Right now it's something like this

```
        self.list = ListCtrl(self, tID, style=wx.LC_REPORT
                             | wx.BORDER_SUNKEN
                             | wx.LC_EDIT_LABELS
                             | wx.LC_SINGLE_SEL
                             )
```

My first attempt is to make header texts **bold**, OR create a horizontal rule that separate the header from the items (like in GTK version). I tried wx.LC_HRULES, but it only affects the items, not the header. Can you suggest a way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: wxWidgets (and wxPython) use native controls whenever possible. So this is how native Windows ListCtrl look like. Try to use a different theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tinkering, I found a way to make the text bold. The answer is [Ultimate Listctrl](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.lib.agw.ultimatelistctrl.UltimateListCtrl.html). It's a very flexible class with wonderful customizations.